# After setting ulimit to unlimited, I am not able to login to machine

Tags: unix

In one of requirment, I had to set ulimit on one of my machine to unlimited.

For this I changed following in /etc/security/limits.conf as below

```
# End of file
oracle   soft   nofile    unlimited
oracle   hard   nofile    unlimited
oracle   soft   nproc    131072
oracle   hard   nproc    131072
oracle   soft   core    unlimited
oracle   hard   core    unlimited
oracle   soft   memlock    50000000
oracle   hard   memlock    50000000

*           soft    nofile          unlimited
*           hard    nofile          unlimited
```

and changed /etc/profile

```
if [ $USER = "oracle" ]; then
        if [ $SHELL = "/bin/ksh" ]; then
              ulimit -p unlimited
              ulimit -n unlimited
        else
              ulimit -u unlimited -n unlimited
        fi
fi
```

I logged out. I am not able to connect ot machine at all. could you please someone help on this.

Comment: the man page for `limits.conf` doesn't tell me if `unlimited` is a valid value, so i wonder if it thinks that means `0`.

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is a problem with the `/etc/profile` edit you made, and assuming you are using `ssh` to connect, you can try:

```
ssh youruser@yourhost bash --noprofile
```

`bash` won't load the global or user-specific startup files (so you won't even have a `PS1` variable set, it will look strange).

(I don't know how to do that with Ksh.)

Comment: Awesome!!! It worked I could login to system. I will note this command in my book :) Thank you so much!!!